# How can we prove $1>\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{\varphi{(k)}}{k}\ln{\frac{2^k}{2^k-1}}>1-\frac{1}{2^n}$

Tags: number-theory, inequality

> Let $\varphi$ be Euler's totient function, where $\varphi{(1)}=1$. Prove that for any postive integer $n$ we have
>   $$1>\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\dfrac{\varphi{(k)}}{k}\ln{\dfrac{2^k}{2^k-1}}\right)>1-\dfrac{1}{2^n}$$

Maybe this problem can be solved using integrals.

$$\ln{\dfrac{2^k}{2^k-1}}=\ln{2^k}-\ln{(2^k-1)}$$

But then I don't know how to deal with this term:

$$\dfrac{\varphi{(k)}}{k}$$

Answer (score 5):

For the lower bound:

$$\begin{eqnarray*}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{\phi(k)}{k}\log\left(\frac{2^k}{2^k-1}\right)&=&\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{\phi(k)}{k}\left(-\log\left(1-\frac{1}{2^k}\right)\right)\\
&=&\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sum_{r=1}^{+\infty}\frac{\phi(k)}{kr\cdot 2^{kr}}\\
&=&\sum_{s=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{s 2^s}\sum_{\substack{m\mid s\\m\leq n}}\phi(m)\\
&>&\sum_{s=1}^{n}\frac{1}{s 2^s}\sum_{m\mid s}\phi(m)\\
&=&\sum_{s=1}^{n}\frac{1}{2^s}\\
&=&1-\frac{1}{2^n}.
\end{eqnarray*}$$
The upper bound simply follows from
$$\sum_{\substack{m\mid s\\m\leq n}}\phi(m)\leq s.$$

Answer (score 3):

I have found a proof of the upper bound.

First, note that $2^k>k$ for $k\geq 1$. Then $2^k(k-1)<k(2^k-1)$ or
$$\frac{k-1}k\frac1{2^k-1}<\frac 1{2^k}$$

Now,

$$\frac{\varphi(k)}k\ln\left(\frac{2^k}{2^k-1}\right)<\frac{k-1}k\frac1{2^k-1}<\frac1{2^k}$$

Hence, the sum is strictly upper bounded by the geometric series
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac 1{2^k}=1$$

Comment: It's good Job.+1

Comment: maybe other bounded can use Integral.

Comment: I have tried Euler's and Abel's summation formulas. Also tried the assymptotic formula $\sum_{n\leq x}\frac{\varphi(n)}n=\frac{6n}{\pi^2}+O(\ln x)$. No result.